# Calculate Yyars based on date and timezone

Tags: mysql, sql

I am helping a non-profit charity who have offices in a few countries where each admin person in each country needs to regularly export a report of around 4,500 people who have donated funds over the years. Annoyingly, they cannot change the way they store data, as this comes from an export in their aged charity management system.

I understand we might need a separate database of timezones, with some way to reference that, so any help would be very useful.

The database holds names, the date they gave the donation along with their timezone.

The structure looks like

```
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `timezone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_donated` date NOT NULL,
```

and a snippet of data looks like

```
(44, 'K Jones', 'Europe/Brussels', '2021-01-22'),
(50, 'H D Wakefield', 'Australia/Sydney', '2019-04-18'),
(52, 'F Davies', 'Europe/London', '2014-02-04');
```

So from this data, they have a standard query used, that displays the data on a front-end internal website page, and the current query looks like.

```
SELECT contact_name as ContactName, timezone as Timezone, date_donated as DonationDate FROM `donations` WHERE id > 100
```

What they need to do, is add another field called something like "DonationGivenYears", and show the number of years since the donation, based on the timezone in the database, but using the timezone of the person in the admin office as the reference point.

So someone in London may get a slightly different number of years value than the person in the Sydney office depending on what time they run the query.

They do have a list of staff and their timezones, it's contained in a `staff` database and looks like

```
(`id`, `name`, `timezone`)
(3, 'Steve', 'Europe/London')
(12, 'Sarah', 'Australia/Sydney')
```

So the result would look something like

```
ContactName     Timezone           DonationDate     DonationGivenYears
K Jones         Europe/Brussels    2021-09-27       0
H D Wakefield   Australia/Sydney   2019-04-18       3
F Davies        Europe/London      2014-02-04       8
```

With this query, the person in Sydney might get 1 for K Jones, as it's nearly Thursday, whereas the person in London might get 0 as it's still Wednesday.

I'm racking my brain on how this might work in a query, and wondering if this is at all possible?

If so, how would I go about doing this, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Tag that in your question.

Comment: Hi Mark, it's MySQL, but I have tagged that, I don't think it saved that option when I originally submitted it. Thanks

Comment: You had tagged SQL and database (which is pretty much a useless tag).

Comment: I don't think it is possible at the database level, you could do it at the application level, can you mention the application level technology if it will help?

Comment: I did, but sadly it needs to be done via the SQL command, would it then be possible to just do the first part without changing it for different staff. So it just shows the number of years as per the timezone of the fundraiser?